# How to sort strings in java , order shoud display Capital Strings first

Tags: java, string, sorting, capitalize

Need to sort strings in java in a case sensitive, but Capital letters should display first.

**What I tried:**

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("aaa","AAA","AAA","aaa","BBB","ccc","CCC");
l.stream().sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
System.out.println(l);`
```

**Output:**

```
[aaa, AAA, AAA, aaa, BBB, ccc, CCC]
```

**Expecting Output:**

```
[AAA,AAA,aaa,aaa,BBB,CCC,ccc]
```

Comment: @PaulLemarchand updated my question. need to sort strings, not char.

Comment: What if it has strings like `AAa` or `aAA` or `AaA`?

Comment: See my UPDATED answer

Comment: @user7 then AAa,AaA,aAA should be the order.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Do you want to list the string that has most consecutive upper-case (comparing char by char from beginning) chars first? Then what about strings with different lengths like [`AA`, `AAa`]

Comment: See my recent edit and if it satisfies your need.

Comment: @user7 this work's for my question. l.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            int compareIgnoreCaseResult = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
            if (compareIgnoreCaseResult != 0){
                return compareIgnoreCaseResult;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        });

Answer (score 2):

You can add a second comparator to decide on the ordering after you have compared them ignoring the case. The second comparator orders based on the casing of the characters.

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a","A","A","a","B","c","C");
l.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(YourClass::isUpperCase)
             .reversed()));
    
private static boolean isUpperCase(String s) {
    return Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
}
```

The `Comparator.comparing` uses a helper method to determine if a string is upper cased. The return type of this method is a *boolean*. The natural ordering of boolean is *false* followed by *true*. Hence, you have to reverse it to get the upper-cased characters (strings) first.

**Note:** You should have used characters rather than strings here (if all the Strings have just one character). The helper method here just checks for the first character in this String which sounds odd!.

Alternatively, if you have a method for checking for lower case, you can simplify this as

```
l.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
      .thenComparing(YourClass::isLowerCase));

private static boolean isLowerCase(String s) {
    return Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(0));
}
```

**UPDATE:** (as per OP update of the question).

If the string has multi characters and if you want to order based on the condition that upper-cased strings must come first before others, you can do like.

```
l.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
        .thenComparing(YourClass::areAllCharactersLowerCase));

private static boolean areAllCharactersLowerCase(String s) {
    return s.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
            .allMatch(Character::isLowerCase);
}
```

**Note:** With this, string like `CCc` and `Ccc` will be treated equal as per the first comparator and the second comparator will return false for both (treating them equal again). So, they appear in the same order as appeared in the input.

---

**EDIT 2:** Based on the OP comment

> What if it has strings like AAa or aAA or AaA?
>
> @user7 then AAa,AaA,aAA should be the order.

I guess your intention is to order the strings by comparing character by character and the string that has the most consecutive upper-cased character will be considered to be listed before others.

The below code compares char-by-char and handles the following scenarios

- If the current char of String `a` is upper-cased and the current char of String `b`is lower-cased, then String `a` comes before `b`.
- If the current char of String `a` is lower-cased and the current char of String `b`is upper-cased, then String `b` comes before `a`
- Else, both have same char.. Keep searching.

For equal strings, we return 0 at the end.

```
 l.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
        .thenComparing((a, b) -> {
            //String a and b are equal when compared ignoring case (and hence same length)
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(i)) && Character.isLowerCase(b.charAt(i))) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)) && Character.isUpperCase(b.charAt(i))) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is custom sort, not a case sensitive sort. Because in case-sensitive sort, all capital letters will stand before small letters. Therefore, the result will be

```
AAA > BBB > CCC > aaa > bbb > ccc
```

To realize your custom sort, you need to use a custom Comparator, as follows

```js
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SortCapitalFirst {

    @Test
    public void runTest(){
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList("aaa","AAA","AAA","aaa","BBB","ccc","CCC");
        l.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            int compareIgnoreCaseResult = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);

            if (compareIgnoreCaseResult != 0){
                return compareIgnoreCaseResult;
            }

            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        });
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: @anhqan, I didn't mention "case sensitive sort", I need sort as expected in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if(o1 == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if(o2 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                int result = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
                if(result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        };

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A","a","A","a", "B", "c","C");
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        System.out.println(list);
        // [A, A, a, a, B, C, c]

        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Ab","a","AB", "A", "AbB", "a","B","c","C");
        Collections.sort(list2, comparator);
        System.out.println(list2);
        // compare length first
        // [A, a, a, AB, Ab, AbB, B, C, c]

        List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("aaa","AAA","AAA","aaa","BBB","ccc","CCC");
        Collections.sort(list3, comparator);
        System.out.println(list3);
        // [AAA, AAA, aaa, aaa, BBB, CCC, ccc]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code help you to sorting string in CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER. Here you need two time sorting for list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a", "A", "A", "a", "B", "c", "C");
  Collections.sort(l);
  Collections.sort(l, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: @MohanReddy  my answer sort the strings not char.

Comment: Thank you, your answer working as I expected. but why need to call 2 times sort()?  any explanation?

Comment: On first sorting with `CASE_SENSITIVE_ORDER` so all upper case words are come first and lower case words are last. like [A, A, B, C, a, a, c]
When we perform second sorting with `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` then it only arranges lower case words. like [A, A, a, a, B, C, c]